# Take out Infinite loop for page view controller setup

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have been trying to create an opening scene that has 3 views which are embedded within a page view controller. The goal was to create something like Instagram where you have your social media feed in the middle and then when you swipe right it takes you to a view and if you swipe left it takes you to a different view. However, with my current code, the view controllers swipe infinitely and I was wondering if anyone knew how to fix this.

Here is how my current setup looks:
[Current Setup of Page Views](https://youtu.be/QiIZFf_akjc)

Here is how I want it to look like: 
[What I want the functionality to be](https://youtu.be/MB1IGKs5AHg)

Here is my page view controller code. i have a main page view controller linking the other 2 views.

```
class HomeRootPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    lazy var viewControllerArray: [UIViewController] = {
        return [self.ViewControllerInstance(name: "FeedViewController"),
               self.ViewControllerInstance(name: "DMViewController"),
               self.ViewControllerInstance(name: "ProfileViewController")]
    }()

    private func ViewControllerInstance(name: String) -> UIViewController {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: name)

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self

        if let firstViewController = viewControllerArray.first {
            setViewControllers([firstViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }


    public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        guard let viewControllerIndex = viewControllerArray.index(of: viewController) else {
            return nil
        }

        let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1

        guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
            return viewControllerArray.last
        }

        guard viewControllerArray.count > previousIndex else {
            return nil
        }

        return viewControllerArray[previousIndex]

    }

    public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        guard let viewControllerIndex = viewControllerArray.index(of: viewController) else {
            return nil
        }

        let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1

        guard nextIndex < viewControllerArray.count else {
            return viewControllerArray.first
        }

        guard viewControllerArray.count > nextIndex else {
            return nil
        }

        return viewControllerArray[nextIndex]

    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:

```
guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
    return viewControllerArray.last
}
```

And this:

```
guard nextIndex < viewControllerArray.count else {
    return viewControllerArray.first
}
```

Those 2 block of codes, are responsible for looping your viewControllers. Simply removing them will give you results you are looking for.

Comment: that causes a crash on this line : return viewControllerArray[previousIndex]. The error says fatal error: index out of range.

Comment: Maybe inverting the viewControllerArray.last and viewControllerArray.first  positions .Since if the index is lower that 0 you wanna to show the first page not the last

Comment: Or just return nil